# jQuery ajax form still submits WITH page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, refresh

I've got a pretty straightforward jQuery AJAX piece of code that should submit the form without a page refresh but for some reason it's being ignored and the form is being submitted as normal.

The jQuery code:

```
$(".createEvent").live('click', function() { 

                $(".eventResult").html($("<img/>").attr("src", "<?php echo __FULL_PATH; ?>images/loader.gif").attr("id", "loader"));
                $('.eventResult').show();  
                var form =  $(this).parents('form:first');
                var eventName = $("input[name='eventName']",form).val();
                var eventID = $("input[name='eventName']",form).id();

                  var dataString = 'eventName ='+ eventName;  
                  $.ajax({  
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "{site.createPageURL}"+eventID+"/event/",  
                  data: dataString,  
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(html) {  
                    alert('done');
                    $('.eventResult').html(html);  
                    $('.eventForm').hide(); 
                    updateBookingList(eventID);             

                  } 
                });  
                return false; 

        });
```

and the form:

```
<form id="eventForm_1318915800" method="POST" action="path_here..." name="eventForm">
<label for="eventName">Please enter a name for the event</label>
<input id="1318915800" type="text" name="eventName">
<label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>
<input class="createEvent" type="submit" value="Create event" name="submit">
</form>
<div id="eventResult_1318915800" class="eventResult">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Please check the function updateBookingList(eventID) for any redirect or refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an indication of JS error in the middle - which bypass the `return false`

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what was happening. Thank's for the tip - I actually didnt know that Firebug could break on Javascript errors so I was able to pick up a very useful debugging method as a result.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the `event.preventDefault();` before you call the ajax. Your function should be modified as below:

```
$(".createEvent").live('click', function(event) { 
     event.preventDefault();
     .
     .
     .
     //ajaxCall
});
```

Comment: This won't prevent a submission triggered from the keyboard.

Comment: Yup. Better to use $("#eventForm_1318915800").live('submit', function(){})

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop the form submitting you are probably better doing:

```
$("#eventForm_1318915800").submit(function () { return false; });
```

This is better because it will also handle a submit triggered by the Enter key for example.